# SQL Sub query with Computations

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables Tablle1, Table2, Table3. 
Table1 & Table2 are related by Id1.
Table2 & Table3 are related by Id2.

1. I have the following query which works. How do I get CTotal = C00+C01+C02?
2. Where do I add the OUTPUT statements to return the values of STOTAL & CTOTAL?

```
SELECT X.Id1, X.S00, X.S01, X.S02, X.S00 + X.S01 + X.S02 AS STOTAL,
       CEILING(X.S00 / @Size) AS C00, CEILING(X.S01 / @Size) AS C01, 
       CEILING(X.S02 / @Size) AS C02,
       Tble1.Select00, Table1.Select01, Table1.Select02

FROM(
    SELECT Table1.Id1, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Select00 = 1 THEN Table3.Num00 ELSE 0 END) AS S00, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Select01 = 1 THEN Table3.Num01 ELSE 0 END) AS S01, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Table1.Select02 = 1 THEN Table3.Num02 ELSE 0 END) AS S02
    FROM  Table1 INNER JOIN
                Table2 ON Table1.Id1 = Table2.Id1 INNER JOIN
            Table3 ON Table2.Id2 = Table3.Id2
        WHERE  (Table1.Id1 = @Id1
    )
    GROUP BY Table1.Id1) AS X INNER JOIN  Table1  ON X.Id1 = Table1.Id1
```

Comment: Where's C03 in your query? I don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add `CEILING(X.S00 / @Size) + CEILING(X.S01 / @Size) + ... AS CTotal` or use derived table:

```
SELECT a.*, a.C01+a.C02+a.C03 AS CTotal FROM
(
    [your_old_query]
)a
```

Another alternative to derived table - CTE(common table expression)

Comment: I will be lazy and not type the rest of my answer since @a1ex07 pretty much did it for me :D. Cheers.

Comment: Just one thing, since C01 to C03 are defined in the inner query, wouldn't the outer query need to reference it as `a.C01+a.C02+a.C03`?

Comment: @Anthony Accioly: you are right, it's better to reference with alias (not necessary though in this case, just one "table"). Fixing...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the query with one more outer select and add it all together.